# Connect Azure Repo to AWS Amplify

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, aws-amplify, azure-repos

I have an app that resides in Azure repo. When trying to deploy to Amplify, seems like Azure is not an option as a provider. Does anybody know how these two could be integrated?

Restraint: Cannot switch the repo to another provider.